# Show canvas when loaded (CSS animation)

Tags: javascript, css, animation, canvas

I have a simple webpage with the canvas (width 100%, height 300px) on top, and it needs to load circa 10mb of stuff, so it might take a few seconds. Is there a way to hide this canvas until it is completely loaded, and than, smoothly reveal it from the top - so both the canvas and web content below it would smoothly go down?

I have no clue if this is possible, or how to do it.

Any help?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried something? Can we see your attempts?

Comment: Yup, definitely possible.

Comment: Fabrizio: Not really. I managed to track when the Javascript 'app' us fully loaded, so I am able to set some flag variable there, but I have no clue how to implement it to html/css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hide the canvas via css like this:

```
<canvas id="mycanvas" style="display:none"></canvas>
```

And when the the content is fully loaded you can use jquery to slide it down like this:

```
$( "#mycanvas" ).slideDown();
```

Here is more info:
http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/